# SQL injection - update two tables at once in a non-stacked mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I'm learning some advanced SQL injection techniques, but eventually I find something harder.

I've got a PHP code like this(I can't change this, **it's PHP + MySQL 5.6.19[InnoDB]**):

```
$newValue = $_POST['newvalue'];
if ($newValue > 1000)
    mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `column1`='".$newValue."' WHERE `id`='".$id."'");
```

I've already worked out a way to fool PHP a little bit by passing a valid number at the beginning in POST parameter, like this(this one changes other column value, that's nice, **works**):

```
1001', `column2` = 'some_value' WHERE `id` = 'some_other_value';#
```

Now I'd like to change(UPDATE) other table in the same UPDATE query. **Remember! I can't change the code and mysql_query doesn't allow stacked queries(you can't perform multiple queries separating them by a semicolon).**

In theory, it might look like this(of course, it doesn't work):

```
1001' WHERE `id` = 'some_other_value' OR (UPDATE `table2` SET ... = ... LIMIT 1);#
```

or(some theoretical trick):

```
1001'*(UPDATE `table2` SET ... = ... LIMIT 1) WHERE `id` = 'some_other_value';#
```

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you for help.

Comment: Both values are integers right? Cast them as such and you should be all set.

Comment: @chris85 I think you didn't get the idea. I'm at the attacker position, not programmer.

Comment: Aha, yup read that wrong.

Comment: Just take a closer look at the [`UPDATE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) and [expression syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/expressions.html).

Comment: There's no union for update commands, you can't do it  this way. Maybe if you find some OS interaction command or an additional vulnerable stored function which can be used with stacked queries - then this would be possible.
Any way you can however get any data using this SQL Injection, read my white paper - search for "SQL Injection Anywhere" in Google.
Try searching for "